# If or statement in php not evaluating correctly

Tags: php

I have this PHP statement:

```
if (($row['rest'] != "") or ($row['rest'] != "Select An Option")) {
    $rest = "<b>Rest Stops:</b> {$row['rest']},";
}
else {
    $rest = "";
}
```

which is not evaluating properly and I can't figure out why.  What I want the statement to do is if the field 'rest' is blank or "Select An Option" then the variable $rest should evaluate to "Rest Stops:" followed by the data.  My data is "Select An Option" and I get "Rest Stops: Select An Option" as the output.  I did some testing of this statement and I figured out PHP is assigning the variable $row['rest'] as not equal to "" instead of evaluating the 'or' statement.  What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want the statement to do is if the field 'rest' is blank or `Select An Option` than the variable `$rest` should evaluate to `Rest Stops:` followed by the data.

Your logic is incorrect. You need to check if they are *equal to*, so use `==` instead of `!=`.

```
if ($row['rest'] == ""  || $row['rest'] == "Select An Option") {
^--------------------^     ^--------------------------------^
if field 'rest' blank        if field is 'Select An Option'
```

This can be be improved by using [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) to perform the "is empty" check:

```
if (empty($row['test']) || $row['rest'] == "Select An Option") {
```

Answer (score 0):

"If the field 'rest' is blank ...." - if that's true, then your logic is backwards:

```
if ($row['rest'] == '') || ($row['rest'] == 'Select an option') {
    $rest = 'rest stops';
} else {
    $rest = '';
}
```

Note the use of `==` for equality, rather than `!=` for inequality.